# I need to get all entries in MySQL table licenses where the number column contains BOTH letters and number

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table called `licenses` that holds all my users professional license numbers. There is a field, `lic_type` that holds the official letter code for the professional license, "PN", "RN", "RT", "APRN", "EO", etcetera. There is another column in the same licenses table, `number`, that holds the numeric portion of the full license information, 2261234, 1234567, etcetera, but the field is not INT it is varchar(18) due to need for some strings (see later in this question). I am NOT able to change the database structure or the type of the `number` column. Currently, when I concat these two fields together, it should give the full license designation.

For example - if lic_type is "RN" and number is "2676612", then when they are concatenated, they produce the correct license for the individual - RN2676612. However, the database I have received contains SOME entries in `number` column that contain the full license, i.e. RN2676612, instead of just numbers. Sometimes the letters are not even the right code. For example, the `lic-type` may be "PN", but they may have entered "LPN2261123", so that I cannot search for the entry in `lic_type` in the `number` column.

I need an MySQL query that will return ANY row where `number` contains any letters and at LEAST one number.  I must allow full letter entries in `number` such as STUDENT or WAITING, but they will always have NO numbers, so, any entry in `number` that has a letter and a number is invalid and I need to correct. This allows me to bypass all letter numbers when pulling information from fully licensed customers.

Currently, I have tried the following query (in **phpMyAdmin**):

```
SELECT * FROM `licenses` WHERE `number` REGEXP '(?=.*\d) (?=.*[A-Z])[\d|\w]*'
```

which I borrowed from a license plate example.

But it returns an error:

```
#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp.
```

Please help!

Comment: You'd need ``WHERE `number` REGEXP "[[:alpha:]].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[[:alpha:]]"``

Comment: Worked perfect. I am not a expert REGEX user. Could you please explain your answer, so I can modify it if needed later for similar issues? For example if I only wanted a field whose entry STARTED with letters, not ended with.

Comment: Provide data showing examples of every cases.

Comment: @Rick James - The solution was already given and accepted prior to you posting your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
WHERE `number` REGEXP "[[:alpha:]].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[[:alpha:]]"
```

Here,

- `[[:alpha:]].*[0-9]` - matches a letter, then any zero or more chars and then a digit
- `|` - or (since a digit may precede a letter)
- `[0-9].*[[:alpha:]]` - matches a digit, then any zero or more chars and then a letter.